# Extend DbContext class using Ef6

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, .net-assembly

I need to extend the generated dbcontext in my application using EF6

```
namespace DAL.Entities
{
    using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    using System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects;
    using System.Linq;

    public partial class ajtdevEntities : DbContext
    {
        public ajtdevEntities()
            : base("name=ajtdevEntities")
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
        }

        public virtual DbSet<ajt_adress> ajt_adress { get; set; }
}
}
```

When I tried to change the name of this class **ajtEntities1** to **ajtdevEntities**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace  DAL.Entities
{
    public partial class ajtEntities1 
    {
    }
}
```

I get this exception :

[image: error]

I don't understand why this exeption is appeared!!

1. What is the reason?
2. How can I fix it?

Comment: What happens when you simply type the name instead of using visual studio rename feature?

Comment: @dotctor it works !!! but I have to verify the full code to replace the name manually!!

Comment: Have you tried building the project before performing the rename?

Comment: @dotctor Yes I build and re-build the solution and I run it but I got the exception ( using rename feature of course)

Comment: Do you use ef designer ? If that is true; you should change your entity name from degisner.